# Push to Webpage

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

How does Facebook and other pages seem to automatically push to webpages? They arent continually refreshing.

I know it would be through javascript but am a bit unsure on the theory. Is there a javascript script that is continuelly checking back with the facebook server to see if any updates are created?

Can someone point me into the right direction to where i can research how to add this functionality to my webpage? 
(Its probably more a javascript thing, however I am using C# ASP.NET)

Comment: Push what to where? Can you make an example?

Comment: your way of putting up a question seems weird..Could you please provide an example

Answer (score 1):

AJAX:

- What is AJAX? http://www.google.co.uk/search?aq=f&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=ajax
- jQuery AJAX: http://www.google.co.uk/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=jquery+ajax

Answer (score 1):

I belive they use a "keep-alive" session combined with some of the technology explain at wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about the way facebook updates your news feed automatically in your browser when you friends post new stories, then the answer is [**http streaming**](http://ajaxpatterns.org/HTTP_Streaming).

I can't tell you the exact implementation they are using, but the basics of it is that they use [**xhr**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest) (often referred to as *ajax*) to do [**long polling**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology#Long_polling) against their servers and then use js to manipulate the DOM whenever new data comes in.

A popular way to implement this kind of functionality is to use [**comet streaming**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29)

Answer (score 0):

You should also take a look at [Server-Sent Events](http://dev.w3.org/html5/eventsource/).

Answer (score 0):

They keep checking for very small Boolean variable on server that is created within your session object and updates continuously (don't know the interval maybe 1 to  5 seconds)

once they found this variable changed, they look for bigger variable (like your friends post) than this , if they found that change they look for even bigger variables (like every other subscription you have)

All these happens Asynchronously at process runs on server without informing you unless they are completed.

Data comes from web-services and bind to your page asynchronously using JavaScript by manipulating DOM objects of web page.

Answer (score 0):

eh just wanted to ad some detail. HTTP is statesless. so there is no notion of pushing. You need to understand this. very important. **HTTP is stateless**.

So how does it do?

Open a firebug and watch the traffic, for facebook and gmail etc. you ll see there is constant XMLHTTPRequests being send to servers. if there is a new message, it s acquired and your front end it updating your UI. so they are using AJAX.

That s what s happening.

THere is socket.io now, which can push to client, but that s another story.

Answer (score -1):

I used dwr to implement push some information to the web. It may work like this, first the web JS do post to the, then the web hold on this call untill the web need push something to web or time out. Then the web call the callback function you registered before.